# How to integrate payumoney payment gateway in joomla 3.5

Tags: joomla3.0

I'm trying to integrate Pay U Money payment gateway in my client site. My client provided me the login details of Pay U Money. site is built in joomla 3.5.

Comment: What have you already tried? What is not working? If you're looking for a Joomla plugin, a simple Google search (https://www.google.com/?hl=nl&gws_rd=ssl#hl=nl&q=payumoney+joomla) already gave some very good results.

Comment: You should probably study https://www.payumoney.com/websiteintegration.html